# настройка сети в ubuntu server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сеть

решил попробовать настроить ubuntu server 16.04. завис на самом начальном этапе. это настройка сети. в файле etc/network/interfaces (iface enp1s0 inet static, address, netmask, gateway, dns-nameservers, auto enp1s0) прописал все настройки, перезагрузил network, но сети все равно нету. другие компьютеры в сети не видят его ip. при вызове команды sudo lshw -C network напротив нужной сетевухи раньше писал **disabled**,  после ввода настроек **disabled** пропало. систему тоже перезагрузил. но все равно не работает.

Comment: По бубунтам манов в сети больше чем по выни - http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D1%80%D1%83%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E - раз, два - http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE_ubuntu_server/%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C/%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8 для примера.

Comment: @SeyDee настроил все согласно этим инструкциям, но не работает.

Comment: по такому описанию, сложно предположить хоть что то, кроме общих советов. Но я даже не помню, когда подобные настройки мне нужны были  - все само заводится. Но может старая кривая сетевая?

Comment: @kemozn дай вывод lspci, может действительно сетевуха "кривая", не поддерживается.

Comment: @KoVadim подскажите какие данные надо я напишу.

Comment: @SeyDee сетевуха новая. только вставил. была встроенная, на ней тоже не работало. по части сетевых карт вывод такой `01:00.0 ethernet controller: d-link system inc dge-528t gigabit ethernet adapter (rev 10) <br/> 02:00.0 ethernet controller:qualcomm atheros attansic l2 fast ethernet (rev a0)`

Comment: с соседнего компа на винде пишу команду arp -a показывает его ip,  а через ping теряет все пакеты

Comment: погуглил по именам карт. По первой все жалуются и вроде не могут завести. По второй - заводят(вроде), но с бубнами.

Comment: @KoVadim надо на них драйвера что ли ставить? у меня просто ip все статические. поэтому автоматически при установке сеть не настраивается. а в ручную почему то не дает.

Comment: похоже, что нужно будет помучатся с правильной сборкой модулей

Comment: @KoVadim не могли бы подсказать с чего начать изучать данный вопрос?

Comment: я собственно выше и написал - с гуглить на тему сетевых+ОС. И читать, читать форумы.

Comment: Сеть на статике? О_о Зачем?

Comment: подсказываю наиболее простое решение: подключите сетевую карту, которая нормально поддерживается программой linux (обе упомянутые имеют явные проблемы). и будет вам счастье.

Answer (score 0):

```
iface enp1s0 inet static, address, netmask, gateway, dns-nameservers, auto enp1s0
```

Попробуй `auto enp1s0` в начало, перед `iface enp1s0 inet static` написать. Мне помогало пару раз .